# Eclipse CDT for Android C/C++

Tags: android, c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to setup Eclipse IDE to help me manage and navigate through the C/C++ source for android.

Following the instructions on http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html I have a local copy of the source and following the instructions on http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html I have setup Eclipse to navigate the Java source.

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and have installed CDT 8.0.2 for Eclipse indigo so I have the C/C++ development tools. What I now need to do is set up the various projects for the android source.

Is the a simple way to create a project from the exising source which will index all of the code so I can navigate between function calls? Simply which level in my directory structure do I have to do the "New Project from Existing Source" call? Is there already a configuration like the .classpath used for the Java setup?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Android plugin for eclipse (through eclipse: help -> install new software) and fill in https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
It is recommended that you use the generic eclipse, not the cdt. You can install the cdt plugin in the same way.

If you have cdt: create new project: c++ from existing code. Voila.

Comment: Hi the ADT plugin for eclipse (http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) is to help build Android applications.

What I am after is a tool to help manage and navigate the android source (i.e. from http://source.android.com/).

I guess CDT and creating new projects from source is the best way.